# Python selection sort dataframe rows

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, selection

```
import pandas as pd
data9 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:170, 'NEW',90.1060,'Agency'], [1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:144, 'Trade',90.1050,'Principal'], [1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:120, 'NEW',90.1022,'Agency'],[1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:100, 'NEW',90.1070,'Agency'], [1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:155, 'NEW',90.1051,'Principal']], columns=['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

I have to find the rows in the dataframe where those conditions are met:

I want to select an sort rows so that: OrderDirection is “SELL”, then the Price of “PRINCIPAL” element in OrderType with its corresponding “TRADE” element in OrderStatus column should *be greater* than the Price of the “AGENCY” element in OrderType column with its corresponding “NEW” element in OrderStatus column.
So that the resulting table has only the below rows. To do that it has to interate through the entire dataframe and find all sets of rows that met the condition above.

```
[1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:120, 'NEW',90.1022,'Agency']
[1, 2, 3, 03:10:20:144, 'Trade',90.1050,'Principal']
```

I got the error: 
KeyError: 'the label [True] is not in the [index]'

How can I solve it?

Below the code:

```
 def selection_sort(nums):
        # This value of i corresponds to how many values were sorted
        for i, row in nums.iterrows():
        # We assume that the first item of the unsorted segment is the smallest
            lowest_value_index = i
            # This loop iterates over the unsorted items
            for j in (i + 1, range(len(nums.F))):
                if row.loc[row['G'] == 'Agency', 'F'].iloc[lowest_value_index] > row.loc[row['G'] == 'Principal', 'F' ].iloc[j]:
                    lowest_value_index = j
            # Swap values of the lowest unsorted element with the first unsorted
            # element
    row.loc[row['G'] == 'Principal', 'F'].iloc[i], row.loc[row['G'] == 'Agency', 'F'].iloc[lowest_value_index]  =  row.loc[row['G'] == 'Agency' , 'F'].iloc[lowest_value_index], row.loc[row['G'] == 'Principal', 'F'].iloc[i]

    selection_sort(data19)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

you can try `.sort_values()` and `.rank()`.  Here's what I have from your supplied DataFrame (the time field needs quotations marks, BTW).

```
data9 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3, '03:10:20:170', 'NEW', 90.1060, 'Agency'],
        [1, 2, 3, '03:10:20:144', 'Trade', 90.1050, 'Principal'],
        [1, 2, 3, '03:10:20:120', 'NEW', 90.1022, 'Agency'],
        [1, 2, 3, '03:10:20:100', 'NEW', 90.1070, 'Agency'],
        [1, 2, 3, '03:10:20:155', 'NEW', 90.1051, 'Principal']
        ], columns=['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G'])
```

Sort by columns F and G, though you could probably add temporary enumeration for the nominal values to ensure they're sorted in the proper direction for you purposes. Or, add in the time column.

This ordering scheme just happens to work here because:

- "Agency" < "Principal",
- 90.1022 < 90.1050,
- "NEW" < "Trade", and
- 03:10:20:120 < 03:10:20:144.

Anyway, `.sort_values()` can also be `inplace` if you want to use that.

```
In [0]: data9 = data9.sort_values(by=["F","G"], ascending=[True, True])
```

Call data9 to check the results:

```
In [1]: data9
Out[1]:
   A  B  C             D      E        F          G
2  1  2  3  03:10:20:120    NEW  90.1022     Agency
1  1  2  3  03:10:20:144  Trade  90.1050  Principal
4  1  2  3  03:10:20:155    NEW  90.1051  Principal
0  1  2  3  03:10:20:170    NEW  90.1060     Agency
3  1  2  3  03:10:20:100    NEW  90.1070     Agency
```

Then we can rank over the "F" column (you can use more columns, just include them in a list like when using sort).  After that, we just use the condition for picking the top 2 (anything below 3) and produce similar results to your expected output.

```
In [1]: data9.loc[data9.loc[:, "F"].rank() < 3.0, :]
Out[1]:
   A  B  C             D      E        F          G
2  1  2  3  03:10:20:120    NEW  90.1022     Agency
1  1  2  3  03:10:20:144  Trade  90.1050  Principal
```